# Double escaping along with URL rewrite in IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, coldfusion, iis-7.5

I have a URL(auto-generated) which is having plus( + ) in the path and I was getting 404 for that.

I searched for a while a found that we can enable double encoding using the following:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```

The problem I am facing is with the rewrite rule for that URL, the plus is being replaced with whitespace in the captured groups:

```
<rule name="Test Page Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^test/([\-a-z0-9_.+]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="test/index.cfm?p1={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

e.g.,
For **URL: /test/test+page**

The URL parameter available on the page is `p1: test page`

Is there any workaround for this to capture from the requested URL so that the URL parameter `p1` will have a value of `test+page`(original)?

Comment: You need to change the rule to allow the "+". That replacement is happening long before it gets to the CF server.

Comment: I have already allowed "+" in the pattern `^test/([\-a-z0-9_.+]+)$"`. Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UrlEncode` function. This rule should work for you:

```
<rule name="Test Page Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^test/([\-a-z0-9_.+]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/test/index.cfm" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="test/index.cfm?p1={UrlEncode:{R:1}}" />
</rule>
```